# ARP flows aren't updated by OpenDayLight

Tags: ping, mininet, arp, opendaylight

I have a [Mininet topology working with ODL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q8xC.png). ODL is configured in reactive mode, so when I run my topology there are [two flows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RowSb.png) installed in the OVS switches. If I do a ping from h1 to h4, the traffic goes through switches s1, s5 and s4. The problem I have is the following. When I unplug the link between s1 and s5 I hope to see the ICMP traffic through s1, s2, s3 and s4, because I think the ARP traffic reaches ODL and it installs new flows to make ARP and ICMP traffic work. However, it doesn't happen and the ping between h1 and h4 doesn't work anymore. Is there any solution to this? How can I "reset" de ARP traffic ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I try to restart the controller while the link is unplug and indeed update the new flow. Hope it helps